# How to set up Alerts module in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-calendar-api

In my Asp.net application, I allow users to create Projects, Sub Projects and tasks. Each of them have attributes like start/end date, cost, assigned to, priority, status etc. I have Roles and users creation module as well. Now I want to give user option to add alerts. For Example: If my task is due tomorrow, I should get an email, If Project is getting delayed, Project Manager (a role) should get a notification.

What is a good architecture that can handle alerts in my system?
Should I write a WCF service that keeps running at backend and looks for subscribed alerts for all users and send them alerts as required or is there any API available like Google calendar API that can pick up data from my database (MS SQL Server) and send out alerts as required?

Comment: did you tried something for this on internet ??

Comment: you can use windows service